# keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BUTTON_Y freezing the focus and not able to navigate after that

Tags: java, android, nvidia, keyevent

For Nvidia joystick trying to associate this event to go to search button on the grid view, it is working but it is getting frozen and nothing is happening after that. Suggest me something

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    Log.i(TAG, " :: keyCode ::"+keyCode);
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BUTTON_Y) {
        searchTop.performClick();
        return true;
    }


    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode,event);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to call the super.onKeyUp(keyCode,event) anyway, even after your event handling.

Comment: I don't see the Why.

Comment: It is not working, can you suggest me something else?